# Manipulating Tables in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, data-manipulation

The indexing scheme I'm trying seems so simple (but wrong)... 
data is the name of the table of data imported from an Oracle database.
I tried moving pointer outside of List[....] and successfully tested (In[100]).
I'm new to Mathematica... been going in little circles using Wolfram help tool.
Can someone get me out of rut and point me to a better method?

```
In[100]:= dat[n_, m_] := data[[n, m]];
          dat[1, 3]
Out[102]= 0.70388
In[104]:= List[dat[n, 3], {n, 1, Length[data]}]

During evaluation of In[104]:= Part::pkspec1: The expression n cannot be used as a part specification.

Out[104]= {{{0.00499, 0.00037, 0.70388, 0.00526, 0.00008, 
    0.00006}, {0.00176, 0.00006, 0.31315, 0.00129, 0.01142, 
    0.00016}, {0.00201, 0.00013, 0.32143, 0.00158, 0.01544, 
    0.00041}, {0.00507, 0.00015, 0.7228, 0.00263, 0.00002, 
    0.00001}, {0.00516, 0.00011, 0.72381, 0.0028, 0.00001, 
    0.00001}, {0.00203, 0.00019, 0.31207, 0.00297, 0.01143, 
    0.00044}, {0.00138, 0.00024, 0.26769, 0.00349, 0.00098, 
    0.00018}, {0.00182, 0.00007, 0.31365, 0.00129, 0.01383, 
    0.0002}, {0.00531, 0.00009, 0.72048, 0.00212, 0., 
    0.00001}, {0.00395, 0.00019, 0.60555, 0.00307, 0.00047, 
    0.00007}, {0.0055, 0.00017, 0.72021, 0.00332, 0.00001, 
    0.00001}, {0.00175, 0.00016, 0.30605, 0.00313, 0.00933, 
    0.00035}, {0.00198, 0.00009, 0.29497, 0.00135, 0.01019, 
    0.00023}, {0.00545, 0.00016, 0.72135, 0.00249, 0.00001, 
    0.00001}, {0.00179, 0.00038, 0.33179, 0.00791, 0.01627, 
    0.00097}, {0.00211, 0.00013, 0.31377, 0.00171, 0.01289, 
    0.00031}, {0.00515, 0.00057, 0.7213, 0.00766, 0.00006, 
    0.00018}, {0.00543, 0.00012, 0.72163, 0.0025, 0., 
    0.00001}, {0.00395, 0.00011, 0.72095, 0.00267, 0.00001, 
    0.00001}, {0.00548, 0.00014, 0.72343, 0.00278, 0., 0.00001}}[[n, 
  3]], {n, 1, 20}}
```

Comment: aside to the direct question, as a general principle you should work with lists in their list form.  If you hide your list in a function as you appear to be attempting you loose all the powerful functionality of mathematicas list operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List` function is not meant to extract data in the way you're attempting to do here. `List` is basically just a wrapper that indicates that whatever is inside is a list of things. If you construct a list in Mathematica using the  curly brackets (`{...}`), you're automatically calling the `List` function:

```
FullForm[{1, 2, 3}]
```

which gives:

```
List[1, 2, 3]
```

Always remember that in Mathematica you're invoking named functions, even if it's not immediately obvious. For example, if you type `dat[[1]]`, you're actually invoking the `Part` function. You can see the functions you're using by wrapping your code in `Hold` (which tells Mathematica to just keep your code in its current form) and then in `FullForm` (which tells Mathematica to show you how Mathematica interprets your input internally):

```
FullForm[Hold[ dat[[1]] ]]
```

This results in:

```
Part[dat, 1]
```

So if you want to understand what's happening, read up on the `Part` function and any linked documentation pages in the `Part` documentation.

As for the rest of your question: if you want to have an index run over a range, you can use the `Table` function. This way your code should work:

```
Table[dat[n, 3], {n, 1, Length[data]}]
```

However, I wouldn't even bother with the definition you put on the top. You can access the elements of your data using `Span`s (look up that function in the documentation. `Span`s are abbreviated with the symbols `;;`) and `All` like this:

```
data[[All, 3]]
```

or:

```
data[[1 ;; Length[data], 3]]
```

I would suggest reading these parts of the documentation (you can find them under the Mathematica documentation under F1 as well as using the following online links):

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingElementsOfLists.html

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take.html

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html